# Correct envelope to use for a SOAP request?

Tags: soap, wsdl, envelope

I'm trying to integrate with the SOAP API specified here:

https://api.okpay.com/OkPayAPI?singleWsdl

https://api.okpay.com/OkPayAPI?wsdl

At the moment the code autogenerated from the wsdl files appears to be acting up, so I'm wondering what should be the correct envelope to send and where should I be sending it?

I used this service for testing: http://www.soapclient.com/soapmsg.html . For server address I put in:

```
https://api.okpay.com/
```

And for SOAP Message I put in what my code is currently generating:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Get_Date_Time xmlns="https://api.okpay.com"></Get_Date_Time></Body></Envelope>
```

And the response appears to be a HTML code of a page, rather than an envelope response.

What would be the correct SOAP Action / Message to what Server Address to send in order to invoke the Get_Date_Time method as specified in the WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. The "Server Address" needs to point at the actual service, so in this case
   https://api.okpay.com/OkPayAPI
2. The action can be seen in the WSDL, in this case
   https://api.okpay.com/I_OkPayAPI/Get_Date_Time

Have a look at the WSDL and search for the action I gave above, that should give you an idea for how to find it for other actions.

With those two updates you should get back the response you expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Get_Date_TimeResponse xmlns="https://api.okpay.com">
      <Get_Date_TimeResult>2015-01-31 17:52:37</Get_Date_TimeResult>
    </Get_Date_TimeResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```